# Fill one variable with information from another dataset in R

Tags: r, variables, dataset, fill

I want R to look for the information of a certain variable `INTERVIEW_DATE` in another dataset based on the identifier variable `TUCASEID`, which is identical in both datasets, and write it on the dataset I'm working with. Both datasets have not the same size. The first has 412,611 and the other 20,720.

Something like a look-up in Excel, I guess.

Data I want to have filled:

```
  TUCASEID         AGE MALE BLACK YEAR DATASET INTERVIEW_DAY INTERVIEW_DATE
1   2.0030100e+13  60    1     1 2003    2003             5             NA
2   2.0030100e+13  41    0     0 2003    2003             6             NA
3   2.0030100e+13  26    0     0 2003    2003             6             NA
4   2.0030100e+13  36    0     1 2003    2003             4             NA
5   2.0030100e+13  51    1     0 2003    2003             4             NA
6   2.0030100e+13  32    0     0 2003    2003             4             NA
7   2.0030100e+13  44    0     0 2003    2003             1             NA
8   2.0030100e+13  21    0     0 2003    2003             2             NA
9   2.0030100e+13  33    0     0 2003    2003             6             NA
10  2.0030100e+13  39    0     1 2003    2003             4             NA
```

Source data with the information necessary concerning the variable `INTERVIEW_DATE`:

```
          TUCASEID AGE MALE BLACK YEAR DATASET INTERVIEW_DAY INTERVIEW_DATE
1   2.00301e+13  60    1     1 2003    2003             5      03Jan2003
2   2.00301e+13  60    1     1 2003    2003             5      03Jan2003
3   2.00301e+13  60    1     1 2003    2003             5      03Jan2003
4   2.00301e+13  60    1     1 2003    2003             5      03Jan2003
5   2.00301e+13  60    1     1 2003    2003             5      03Jan2003
6   2.00301e+13  60    1     1 2003    2003             5      03Jan2003
7   2.00301e+13  60    1     1 2003    2003             5      03Jan2003
8   2.00301e+13  60    1     1 2003    2003             5      03Jan2003
9   2.00301e+13  60    1     1 2003    2003             5      03Jan2003
10  2.00301e+13  41    0     0 2003    2003             6      04Jan2003
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206217/discussion-on-question-by-econ-spectre-fill-one-variable-with-information-from-a).